# Cannot import win32ui with the correct version of pywin32 installed

Tags: python, import, pywin32

I would like to `import win32ui, win32con, win32api` but none of them are showing up as being installed even tough I have the correct version of pywin32 installed(Python3.7, 64 bit same as python)

I have tried `from win32 import win32ui` etc. but besides for win32gui that did not work either

```
from win32 import win32gui #<---- This works
import win32ui, win32con, win32api #<---- This does not
```

Here is the error (I am importing the file that has the imports in it so that is why it looks like this, however if I run the file that has the imports in it directly it shows no errors)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/_DEV/python/PythonPlaysAts/window_pos_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from grabscreen import grab_screen
  File "C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\grabscreen.py", line 6, in <module>
    import win32ui, win32con, win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32ui'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063350/python-no-module-named-win32gui-after-installing-pywin32?rq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution already mentioned here.Hope it helps u..
[Python 'No module named win32gui' after installing pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063350/python-no-module-named-win32gui-after-installing-pywin32?rq=1)

Get the required win32 file if u need..
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/