# Python 3.10 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.win32ui'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, importerror, pywin32

I just updated my python from 3.7 to 3.10 and now there are import error's.
While I just needed for `import win32gui` turn into `import win32.win32gui` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65033521/13629335). There seems no other syntax for `import win32ui`, after some research I found this [github report](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1593) that has been closed [with](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1593#issuecomment-714862233):

> That's very helpful, thanks, and I can reproduce this in visual studio
>
> - I didn't consider that an exception was being caught and ignored. Turns out we aren't holding the GIL when we call back into Python -
>   I've no idea why this is different in 3.9 vs other versions, but the
>   fix is simple and is safe in all versions.

While there is suggested to [comment out a line](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1593#issuecomment-713425107) in a file named [win32control](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/Pythonwin/win32control.h#L30) which I apperantly dont have or find. Neither it seems possible in my compiled files that looks like:

> G  ÁàÈ‰ x@;÷Ñ‰

Nor do I understand [the wheel solution](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1593#issuecomment-714870163) and what to do with it, since I am still a beginner with hobby experience in python programming.

**Update** I just found this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/13629335) but not sure if it is related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 'No module named win32gui' after installing pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063350/python-no-module-named-win32gui-after-installing-pywin32)

Comment: @prakashsellathurai well no.. I just linked this question and the suggested answer in my question. This does not solve the issue.

Comment: Just installed *Python 3.10.1* and *PyWin32 303*  (*pc064*) and didn't encounter your problem. So it must be something fishy in your environment.

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for your reply. Since I installed my earlier version of 3.7.2 again pywin works fine even if I run the code with IDLE Shell 3.10. But I have no idea what I did wrong here and how this is related to the issue.

Comment: It's not necessarily something that **you** did wrong. Sometimes install / uninstall are net exactly opposite, and repeating the process, might lead to funny situations. That's why a clean install should be attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it helped me on my other device to just reinstall my older python version, as stated in the comment section:

> @CristiFati thanks for your reply. Since I installed my earlier
> version of 3.7.2 again pywin works fine even if I run the code with
> IDLE Shell 3.10.

This wasnt possible on my new device, but the [Running as a Windows Service](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/tree/main#running-as-a-windows-service) helped me out this time.

> Manually copy pythonservice.exe from the site-packages/win32 directory
> to the same place as these DLLs.